# How to define and instantiate a derived class at once in python?

Tags: python, inheritance

I have a base class that I want to derive and instantiate together. I can do that in java like:

```
BaseClass derivedClassInstance = new BaseClass() {
    @override
    void someBaseClassMethod() { // my statements}
};
```

In python I can derive and and instantiate a base class like:

```
class DerivedClass(BaseClass):
    def some_base_class_method():
        # my statements

derived_class_instance = DerivedClass()
```

I need to sub-class single instances of some objects with minor changes. Deriving and assigning them separately seems like overkill.

Is there a Java-like *one-liner* way to derive and instantiate a class on the fly? Or is there a more concise way to do what I did in python?

Comment: Consider using a tool other than inheritance for this. Maybe whatever behavior you're implementing with method overrides, you could instead pass to the parent as callbacks or something.

Comment: If BaseClass is a Template Method you won't be able to pass a callback or lambda.

Comment: @user2357112 thanks for the suggestion. I am not familiar with callbacks in python. I'll look into that. vz0's answer was a sufficient deterrent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general you won't see this kind of code, because is difficult to read and understand. I really suggest you find some alternative and avoid what comes next. Having said that, you can create a class and an instance in one single line, like this:

```
>>> class BaseClass(object):
...     def f1(self, x):
...             return 2
...     def f2(self, y):
...             return self.f1(y) + y
... 
>>> 
>>> W = BaseClass()
>>> W.f2(2)
4
>>> X = type('DerivedClass', (BaseClass,), {'f1': (lambda self, x: (x + x))})()
>>> X.f2(2)
6
```

Comment: o_0  Consider me warned.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for metaclass programming.

```
class Base(object):
   def test(self):
      print 'hit'
a =type( 'Derived',(Base,),{})()
a.test()
hit
```